# SpringBoot: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-test

Trying to run my tests I get `No qualifying bean of type` exception for one of my repository dependencies.

I have the following setup:

```
@Repository  
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {}

@Service
public class UserService(val userRepository: UserRepository) {}

@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {}

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
class SomeConfigTest {}
```

No qualifying bean exception is thrown for `UserService`'s `UserRepository` dependency.

Comment: The problem could be of improperly Autowired interface or your testclass is not in the same package as that of your components or missing specification of context to load or type of Autowired object is abstract class etc..  Look for these possibilities.

Comment: None of it really.

Comment: Give a try with add the @ContextConfiguration annotation in your test class

Comment: I resolved the issue by using @MockBean on my repositories.

Comment: @GovindParashar Now I can't autowire `@Configuration` class : (

Comment: annotation @ContextConfiguration(classes = {YourBeans.class})